# Code stuck on site even after cleaning caches

Tags: javascript, wordpress, head

I put a script in the head of my Wordpress and it's stuck there, even after I removed it cleared all caches (including server and CDN). I have wait for more than a month and the code is still there.

The code i'm talking about is a simple js script from a live chat.

````
document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.crossorigin="anonymous";b.src="https://js.driftt.com/include/"+c+"/"+a+".js";a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a)}}}();drift.SNIPPET_VERSION="0.3.1";drift.load("my account id");```


Does anyone already had a similar problem?
````

Comment: If the script is still in there, it's still in the header.php file of the active theme.

Comment: The only script in my header.php file is my Google Analytics script.

Comment: Is that code directly in your HTML? Or is it a linked script? When you look at the source code (Ctrl+U), can't you identify the section that includes it? Can you link us to your Wordpress? Did you check your installed plugins?

Comment: Here's my wordpress: https://www.gypcenter.com.br/ It's a linked script and yes, I have checked every single plugin and every single file and there's no sign of it.

Comment: I can't find it anywhere; I inspected the entire site and kept searching for `drift`, found absolutely nothing. Where exactly is it linked? You're saying it's a script tag in the `<head>`? What is the `src`? The debugger tab doesn't show a script being loaded from `js.driftt.com` either. The code in your question is incomplete anyway, where exactly did you copy it?

Comment: The code is being loaded, since the Drift chat it's still being executed on my site (bottom-left corner) and Pagespeed still complaining about it. I put the code on my <head> through a plugin called "Header and Footer Scripts", that insert codes on my wp_head. I still see "js.driftt.com" being loaded when I inspect the page with Crtl+Shift+I.

Comment: The code I'm talking about is:                                                                  
`<!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
<script>
"use strict";
!function() {
 var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
 if (!t.init) ` it's complete om my website, but it's too big to comment here

Comment: You're right; uBlock Origin apparently blocked the script, that's why it didn't appear in my debugger pane. I see it's included in the head dynamically by a script near the end of `<body>`. I don't think we can help you here without admin access to your page though.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to know if anyone had been through a similar issue. Anyway, thanks for your time. Appreciated